# I got a message from an Author Liaison representative. Can someone please give me advice on what to do?

Tags: self-publishing

I have received the message below on Wattpad and I think it's a scam. I am not that good at writing and I doubt that anyone would come to me out of all people. Can someone please help me I don't know what to do?

> Hello HaikyuuMultishipper9,
>
> My name is Anna. I'm an Author Liaison representative, representing W
> e b n o v e l.  I've read the initial chapters and I feel that your
> novel showcases your capabilities as a writer thus, I would like to
> invite you to publish on our platform W e b n o v e l. You may find
> our App on Appstore or Google Play, which has over tens of millions
> installations.
>
> We would like to offer a non-exclusive contract for your novels
> currently on the site, this way, you can keep the novel on the site
> but at the same time also help you tap on the large reader base of on
> our platform with over 60 million unique user views, making it a
> win-win situation.
>
> Please feel free to reach out to me with regards to this, we want to
> understand your needs first and foremost as an author to help you
> reach the target market you want to hit.
>
> If you want to reach out personally, You can contact me at： Facebook:
> https://www.facebook.com/WebnovelEditors Facebook Messenger:
> WebnovelEditors (There should be a space between two words) Instagram:
> WebnovelEditors (There should be a space between two words) Discord:
> Anna#5681 Email: editorwn.anna@gmail.com

Answer (score 4):

[I got the same thing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/52295/got-a-message-from-an-author-liaison-representative-representing-webnovel-about), ignoring it would be the best thing to do. It's just a bot message to get more content on their site.

I say to ignore it because in their legal section, if it's the same site as the one I got, you don't really own your story once it's on their site. Even if you don't plan on publishing or anything later on, still ignore it in case you change your mind later.